# How do I get the name of an object key in a Javascript for...in loop?

Tags: javascript, object, iteration, for-in-loop

I can iterate over an object like this:

```
var obj = {name: "Fred"}

for(var value in obj) {
    // Key should be "name"
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
}
```

How can I find out what key is? Is this possible at all? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try your code, what is `value`?

Comment: Oh okay this is embarrassing.

Comment: Yeah. If you are unfamiliar with a certain construct, such as `for...in`, read the docs first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in . I mean, how did you even decide to use it if you don't know how it works :P ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful

```
var obj = {name: "Fred"}

for(var key in obj) {
    // Key should be "name"
    console.log(key + ": " + obj[key]);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9a3hnytr/)